# changing css style with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a html with 3 radio buttons. Each radio button is contained in a div container. I would like that if a radio button is checked, the background of the div container containing the checked radio-button should become blue, and the background the div containing the other  unchecked radio-buttons should be white. I tried to achieve that with javascript and css, but it does not work. Could someone please help me to write correctly this javascript ?.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .stylingForCheckedRadioButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }

  .stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: #DCDCDC;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkValue(containerId) {
    const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "radiobutton"]');
    let selectedValue;
    for (const rb of rbs) {
      if (rb.checked) {
        document.getElementById(containerId).style = "stylingForCheckedRadioButton";
      }else{
        document.getElementById(containerId).style  = "stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton";
      }
    }
  };

</script>
<body>

<h1>My Radio Buttons</h1>
<div class="stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container1">
  <input id="radiobuttonId1" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId1" name="radiobutton" onclick="checkValue('container1')">
  <label for="radiobuttonId1">Radio button 1</label>
</div>

<div class="stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container2">
  <input id="radiobuttonId2" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId2" name="radiobutton" onclick="checkValue('container3')">
  <label for="radiobuttonId2">Radio button 2</label>
</div>

<div class="stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container3">
  <input id="radiobuttonId3" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId3" name="radiobutton" onclick="checkValue('container3')">
  <label for="radiobuttonId3">Radio button 3</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You’re looking for the `className` property, not the `style` property.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues here. First, you should use the `className` attribute instead of `style` to change the element class.
Secondly, in your function, JavaScript is setting the color of the divs based on the last value in the `rbs` nodeList. This means that your intended div will be styled according to whether or not the last radio button is checked. To change this, query the DOM for a list of all the divs then check each div according to its corresponding radio button based on index.

```js
function checkValue() {
  const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "radiobutton"]');
  rbs.forEach((rb, i) => {
    let div = document.getElementById(`container${i + 1}`);
    div.className = rb.checked ? 'stylingForCheckedRadioButton' : 'stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton';
  })
};
```

```css
.stylingForCheckedRadioButton {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #DCDCDC;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>My Radio Buttons</h1>
  <div class="stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container1">
    <input id="radiobuttonId1" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId1" name="radiobutton" onclick="checkValue()">
    <label for="radiobuttonId1">Radio button 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container2">
    <input id="radiobuttonId2" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId2" name="radiobutton" onclick="checkValue()">
    <label for="radiobuttonId2">Radio button 2</label>
  </div>

  <div class="stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container3">
    <input id="radiobuttonId3" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId3" name="radiobutton" onclick="checkValue()">
    <label for="radiobuttonId3">Radio button 3</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way...

```js
const all_Radios = document.querySelectorAll('#container input[type=radio]');

set_Radios()  // for page initialization

all_Radios.forEach( btRadio => btRadio.oninput = set_Radios )

function set_Radios()
  {
  all_Radios.forEach( bt => 
    bt.closest('label').classList.toggle('checkedClass', bt.checked))
  }
```

```css
#container > label {
  display          : block;
  color            : black;
  background-color : white;
  border-style     : groove;
  border-width     : thin;
  border-color     : #DCDCDC;
  margin-bottom    : 7px;
  width            : 10%;
  height           : 2em;
  border-radius    : 6px;
  min-width        : 10em;
  line-height     : 2em;
  }
#container > label.checkedClass {
  color            : white;
  background-color : blue;
  border-style     : solid;
  border-color     : grey;
  }
```

```html
<h1>My Radio Buttons</h1>

<div id="container">
  <label>
    <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="xxx" >
    Radio button 1
  </label>  
  <label>
    <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="yyy" >
    Radio button 2
  </label>  
  <label>
    <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="zzz" >
    Radio button 3
  </label>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read some topics on [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```js
// All the radio buttons
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('.radio')

// Function to toggle active class
function handleRadioClick(e) {
  // Remove previous active class
  for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].parentNode.classList.remove('active')
  }

  // Add current active class to parent container
  e.target.parentNode.classList.add('active')
}

// Listen for the click event on radios
for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('click', handleRadioClick, false);
}
```

```css
.container {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #DCDCDC;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.container.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="radio" id="btn1" type="radio" value="btn1" name="radio">
  <label for="btn1">Radio button 1</label>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="radio" id="btn2" type="radio" value="btn2" name="radio">
  <label for="btn2">Radio button 2</label>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="radio" id="btn3" type="radio" value="btn3" name="radio">
  <label for="btn3">Radio button 3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event.target to get the parentNode of the input element to set the style using `classList.replace()`. Each click reset the classes of the parent elements to unchecked, then if the event.target is checked e.target.checked, replace the unchecked class with the checked class.

```js
const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "radiobutton"]');

// callback function setSel passing in the event from the listener
function setSel(e) {
  // get parent element of the event target
  let par = e.target.parentNode
  // reset each input to unchecked before checking the event target
  rbs.forEach(item => item.parentNode.classList.replace('stylingForCheckedRadioButton', 'stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton'))
  // if the el is checked we replace the classList with  
  // the desired class that styles as checked
  e.target.checked ?
    par.classList.replace('stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton', 'stylingForCheckedRadioButton') :
    null
}

// loop over the input nodeList and add event to each node 
// in the list with a callback function 'setSel'
rbs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', setSel))
```

```css
.stylingForCheckedRadioButton {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .stylingForCheckedRadioButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  .stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: #DCDCDC;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<body>

  <h1>My Radio Buttons</h1>
  <div class="container stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container1">
    <input id="radiobuttonId1" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId1" name="radiobutton">
    <label for="radiobuttonId1">Radio button 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="container stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container2">
    <input id="radiobuttonId2" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId2" name="radiobutton">
    <label for="radiobuttonId2">Radio button 2</label>
  </div>

  <div class="container stylingForUnCheckedRadioButton" id="container3">
    <input id="radiobuttonId3" type="radio" value="radiobuttonId3" name="radiobutton">
    <label for="radiobuttonId3">Radio button 3</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```